# How do I find the sum of a Fourier series around x=0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fourier-series

For some reason, I haven't written it down, and the lecturer hasn't done it in his notes either, so it's probably in a lecture, which I could rewatch, but that means using up to 9hrs of my time trying to find that little bit about summation of Fourier series.

I got $-1+\sum_{m=0}^∞\frac{-12(-1)^{2m+1}+12}{(2m+1)^2π^2}cos(\frac{(2m+1)πx}{3})$

This should equal to $2x+2$ between $-3$ and (but not including) $0$, and $-2x+2$ between $0$ and (but not including) $3$.

I am asked to find the sum around $x=0$, except from understanding that x is 0, what do I do, is there any special way to calculate the sum of Fourier series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is continous at $x=0$ (or the corresponding left and right limits are equal). Therefore the Fourier series converges to the value of the function at this point.

Comment: So the sum is 2, how do I prove it? Is it enough to say that "the function is continious at $x=0$, which makes the $sum=2$"? When you wrote that I can vaguely remember him mentioning that, but not enough to spark anything of use in my old brain. Would it matter that one side goes to but not including 0, and one goes from and including 0?

Comment: No the last fact does not matter. You do not need to prove it. It is already a proved theorem (see convergence of Fourier series in wikipedia).